# How to load a custom library in Zend Framework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I've been following this guide (http://socialsemanticweb.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/zend-framework-2-create-custom-library.html) but I can't get Zend to see my library (error message below).

Any ideas what could be wrong? thanks

**my folder structure**

[image: http://imgur.com/Uhhm3uk]

**my MyLibraryController.php**

```
<?php

namespace MyLibrary\Mvc\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;

class MyLibraryController extends AbstractActionController {
    public function __construct() {
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        //instantiate your model here and return result
     $result = "test";
     return $result;
    }
}
```

**my autoload_namespaces.php** (inside vendor\composer)

```
<?php

// autoload_namespaces.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(__DIR__);
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'Zend\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/library/',
    'ZendTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendframework/tests/',
    'Symfony\\Component\\Console\\' => $vendorDir . '/symfony/console/',
    'Doctrine\\ORM' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib/',
    'Doctrine\\DBAL' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib/',
    'Doctrine\\Common' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib/',
    'DoctrineORMModule\\' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src/',
    'DoctrineORMModuleTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/tests/',
    'DoctrineModule\\' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/',
    'DoctrineModuleTest\\' => $vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-module/tests/',
    'MyLibrary\\' => $vendorDir . '/MyLibrary/library/',
);
```

**my application.config.php** (I've only added the MyLibrary entry. **I've tried with and without it**)

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'DoctrineModule',
        'DoctrineORMModule',
        'Directory',
        'Helpers',
    'MyLibrary',
```

**error message without adding MyLibrary module in application.config.php**

```
Fatal error: Class 'Directory\Controller\MyLibaryController' not found in D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\module\Directory\src\Directory\Controller\DirectoryController.php on line 17
```

**error message with MyLibrary module entry in application.config.php**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (MyLibrary) could not be initialized.' in D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php:175 Stack trace: #0 D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(149): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModuleByName(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #1 D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php(90): Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->loadModule('MyLibrary') #2 [internal function]: Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager->onLoadModules(Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #3 D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleEvent)) #4 D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library in D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 175
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First off, it's not a module, so the error message you get by adding it to the modules array of app config is to be expected.

Editing `autoload_namespaces.php` to add your library (as you already have) should work.

That said, a more correct way is to add the `autoload` key to your root composer.json file and do the mapping there

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.3.3",
        "zendframework/zendframework": ">2.2.0rc1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"MyLibrary\\": "vendor/MyLibrary/library/"}
    }
}
```

After doing that, from the command line run `composer.phar update`, and it will automatically add your library to the autoload_namespaces file for you. Doing it that way means you don't have to manually edit the file every time you update your other libraries with composer.

To the error itself

> Fatal error: Class 'Directory\Controller\MyLibaryController' not found in D:\work\eclipse\htdocs\directory\module\Directory\src\Directory\Controller\DirectoryController.php on line 17

I'm guessing that with autoloading taken care of, you're just missing a `use` statement in your `DirectoryController` class

```
<?php
namespace Directory\Controller;

// be sure to use your library controller
use MyLibrary\Mvc\Controller\MyLibraryController;

class DirectoryController extends MyLibraryController
{
    //..
}
```